# Selecting cross compiler for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, raspberry-pi, arm

Looking for cross compiler that could help me build application for Raspberry Pi on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I found [official tools on Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) and I suppose that folder `arm-bcm2708` contains cross compilers:

```
arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi
arm-linux-gnueabihf -> arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf
arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf
gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian
gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64
```

I'm confused what directories names is trying to tell me? I know following words:

```
arm - processor type used on Pi
bcm2708 - processor model used on pi
gnueabi - cross-compiler for armel architecture (you can build binary for ARM on PC)
linaro - company that creates multimedia for ARM
4.9.3 - I suppose is GCC compiler version (why it is so old?)
```

Which of compilers I should use for my Pi3 and Pi4?

Comment: Why not build on the RPi? Too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the toolchains [provided by ARM](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads) for your RPI3/4.
If you are running a 32 bit Linux on your RPI3/4, use one of the `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf` toolchains, if use are running a 64 bit Linux on your RPI3/4, use one of the `aarch64-none-linux-gnu` one.

Both 10.2 and 9.2 versions of the two toolchains are working fine on my own Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 system. Of course, you can cross-compile programs with the `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf` toolchain and run them on the 64 bit Linux running on your RPI3/4 as well.

Comment: I suppose if I run 64 bit Linux I still can use 32 bit toolchain arm-none-linux-gnueabihf ?

Comment: I augmented my answer so that ambiguities would (hopefully) be removed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you get the extracted tools setup on your system so they are usable. I want to do this with Eclipse so wonder how to setup the paths or if you install into the main file system.